# How to simulate drop in LAN bandwidth

Tags: c#, windows, networking, lan

A customer is reporting some odd behaviour which I suspect is due to a massive drop on LAN bandwidth (It matches the times when the IT dept pump out windows updates).

I want to simulate this so I can design around it and make our software more robust to this. I have tried manually setting a bunch of copies going at the same time, but it doesn't put enough load.

Is there a tool out there which can swamp the network?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, you can use a tool such as [Clumsy](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html), which provides many configuration options to emulate various scenarii such as packet loss, lag, out-of-order packets, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Install Fiddler, under Rules > Performance> Simulate modem speeds , you can simulate a low bandwidth connection